# Configuration и xml

Tags: java, spring, аннотации, inversion-of-control

Помогите, не могу разобраться. Я начал изучать Spring (IoC Concept), разобрал как можно конфигурировать бины через xml и отдельно через аннотации, но не пойму возможно ли создать бин в java-классе с аннотацией @Configuration и заполнить его поля, например, через сеттеры() в xml конфигурации?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример конфигурирования самого бина непосредственно при его инициализации в контексте, и да - нет, Вы не сможете через сеттеры с помощью хмл конфигурировать бин

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "tcpOutChannel")
public TcpSendingMessageHandler tcpOut(AbstractServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    TcpSendingMessageHandler gateway = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
    gateway.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

    return gateway;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Дополню ответ от @GenCloud.

Можно сконфигурить бины (`@Bean`), если передать в параметры бина-метода значения из Spring-конфига или Spring-properties-файла.

На Spring это можно сделать через `@Value`.
На SpringBoot это можно сделать через `@ConfigurationProperties`.

Примеры:

```
@Value("${group1.group2.param55:defaultValue}")
private String property;

@ConfigurationProperties("acme")
public class AcmeProperties {

    private boolean enabled;

    private InetAddress remoteAddress;

    private final Security security = new Security();

    public boolean isEnabled() { ... }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) { ... }

    public InetAddress getRemoteAddress() { ... }

    public void setRemoteAddress(InetAddress remoteAddress) { ... }

    public Security getSecurity() { ... }

    public static class Security {

        private String username;

        private String password;

        private List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>(Collections.singleton("USER"));

        public String getUsername() { ... }

        public void setUsername(String username) { ... }

        public String getPassword() { ... }

        public void setPassword(String password) { ... }

        public List<String> getRoles() { ... }

        public void setRoles(List<String> roles) { ... }

    }
}
```

Пример прямой передачи параметров в `@Bean`:

```
@Bean
public MyClass myClass(@Value("${group1.group2.param55:defaultValue}") myProperty){
    return new MyClass(myProperty);
}
```

Подробнее можно почитать здесь:

[Spring Boot features - Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

[Reading a List from properties file and load with spring annotation @Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576156/reading-a-list-from-properties-file-and-load-with-spring-annotation-value)